# how to parse a output of command using shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

i have a string like

`a=b c=d e=f g=h i=j j=k`

How to parse this string to get the value of `j`?

Comment: what did you done sor far for this?

Comment: Why "j"? What's unique about it? Is there a fixed pattern?

Comment: How are you getting this string input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With awk:

```
awk '{ for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) { split($i,arr,"=");if (arr[1]=="j") { print arr[2] } } }' <<< "a=b c=d e=f g=h i=j j=k"
```

Look through each space separated field and then further split the fields into an array (arr) delimited on =. If the first subscript of the array is j, print the second subscript.

Answer (score 1):

This will print anything followed by `j=` till upcoming space regardless of column number of `j`.

```
 echo "a=b c=d e=f g=h i=j j=k" |grep -oP 'j=\K[^ ]+'
 k
```

If you mean, the value of last column, which in this case is `j=k`:

```
echo "a=b c=d e=f g=h i=j j=k" |awk '{split($NF,a,"=");print a[2]}'
k
```

Note: Solution 1 is based on `regex` for the value of j, whereas solution 2 is for the last column's value. Its up to you to chose which one fits better to your requirement.

Or using `gensub` of awk:

```
echo "a=b c=d e=f g=h i=j j=k" |awk '{J=gensub(/.*j=([^ ]+).*/,"\\1","g");print J}'
k
```

or using `gawk` match function:

```
echo "a=b c=d e=f g=h i=j j=k" |awk '{match($0,/.*j=([^ ]+).*/,a);print a[1]}'
k
```

or using `sed` back refrencing:

```
echo "a=b c=d e=f g=h i=j j=k"|sed -r 's/.*j=([^ ]+).*/\1/'
k
```

Answer (score 0):

There is lot of ways to do that in bash. The better depends on the strings pattern.

Assuming the pattern would always be `key=value_without_whitespace key2=value2 ...` a way could be:

```
echo "a=b c=d e=f g=h i=j j=k" | grep -P -o 'j=([^ ])' | cut -d '=' -f 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `source`. pass semicolon separated string as file descriptor

```
source <(echo "a=b c=d e=f g=h i=j j=k" | tr ' ' ';')

echo $j

k
```